# match string pattern in python (including numbers and ':')

Tags: python, string, extract

I'm here to ask about how to extract specific type of string in long string in python.

my string = 'start 1: 1.300454 end'

I don't no how to extract only "1: 1.300454" in my string sample.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^start (.*) end$')

my_string = 'start 1: 1.300454 end'

extract = pattern.match(my_string).group(1)
print(extract)
```

Prints

```
1: 1.300454
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split on the substring " end" and take the first part, then split on "start: " and take the last part:

```
my_string = 'start 1: 1.300454 end'
extract = my_string.split(' end', 1)[0].split("start ", 1)[-1]
print(extract)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string slicing. Example for your case.

```
In [7]: def extract_content(string, prefix='start ', suffix=' end'):
   ...:     return string[len(prefix):-len(suffix)]
   ...: 

In [8]: string
Out[8]: 'start 1: 1.300454 end'

In [9]: extract_content(string)
Out[9]: '1: 1.300454'
```